# Provide a message prompt for user input in SQL Developer 3.1.07

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get the user to input the date into a substitution variable but want the prompt message to prompt the user to input the date in the correct format.

```
SELECT claimdate, assessmentid
FROM claimassessment
WHERE claimdate > to_date('&Date_as_yyyy_mm_dd', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

I keep reading that I should be using the ACCEPT and PROMPT keywords but I am using SQL Developer 3.1.07 and these keywords aren't recognised. How would I get the pop up to display a prompt like 'Enter the effective date in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'. The default prompt on the pop up just says 'Enter Substitution Variable'

Comment: I doubt that this is possible to achieve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accept and prompt keywords are recognised in SQL Developer 3.1.07.42.

Here's a demo using this form:

```
accept Date_as_yyyy_mm_dd date format "YYYY-MM-DD" prompt "Enter the effective date in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'"
```

which creates the prompt window with the text you want (the double-quotes around the prompt value aren't necessary in 3.1 but I think they make it clearer; the single quotes aren't preserved either way though in 3.1, but they are in 18.3), and also checks the format of the supplied values; and then uses the accepted value:

[image]

When run as a script (F5) the pop-up window appears with the specified text:

[image]

If I enter a value that doesn't match the format it re-prompts:

[image]

and one it has an acceptable value it uses that substitution variable value in subsequent statements:

[image]

And as long as you've run the `accept` in script mode, you can run your main query as a statement (control-enter) to get results in a grid in a 'Query results' window.

---

As Jeff mentioned, 3.1 is very old - it seems to have been released in February 2012 - so you might want to consider getting a newer version.

[image]

Comment: i stopped at 2 options, but your 3rd is great assuming they're ok with script vs grid output

Comment: I was mostly addressing the assertion that it didn't work; but as long as the `accept` is run in script mode first, you can still use 'run statement' to get grid output, and it seems to remember the last-accepted value.

Comment: so much work to just avoid building a simple app/report in something APEX :)

Comment: Thanks Alex for pointing out that the accept / prompt line does work in 3.1.07! I have used this line in my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Build it into your SUBSTITUTION Variable name

```
SELECT *
  FROM hr.employees
 WHERE hire_date > TO_DATE('&date_mm_dd_yyyy', 'MM-DD-YYYY');
```

[image]

The date format is kind of in the prompt - the user will at least know you want the 2 digit month then the 2 digit day and then the 4 digit year.

Option 2: Use a report with bind variables.

[image]

For the report, instead of using a substitution variable, we're using a BIND. Your query basically stays the same, it's just :X vs &X. The benefit is that your query will be cached in the optimizer once vs multiple times, once for each query...although more recent copies of the database are smart enough to figure this out on it's own.

You can define in the report how the prompt is labeled.

[image]

And the query behind the report

```
SELECT *
  FROM hr.employees
 WHERE hire_date > to_date(:user_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Comment: PS Version 3.1 is very, very old. The latest version is about 7 years old. The current version is 18.3 - although my answer applies equally to both versions.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I didn't like the first option because it feels a bit of a bodge and the second option seemed good although the Bind pop up window did not have the option to set a tool tip value or prompt value in 3.1.07.