# Show only input from user at runtime with sql developer and not the whole code

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is an example and i know this post too:

[How to get input from user at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516930/how-to-get-input-from-user-at-runtime)

When i run this code in sql developer with pl/sql:

```
DECLARE
  a NUMBER;
BEGIN
  a:=&a;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a);
end;
```

I get a prompt for my user input value and i see my input value on the script output.

Ok this works.

But i see the whole code and my input value.

A solution for exactly this example, no sqlplus, prompt or accept and not this post:

[Provide a message prompt for user input in SQL Developer 3.1.07](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022919/provide-a-message-prompt-for-user-input-in-sql-developer-3-1-07)

Is it possible to deactivate the whole code output and only see my input value, is there a sql developer setting?

I'm using:

Oracle SQL Developer

- Version 21.4.1.349
- Build 349.1822
- On a Windows 10 PRO

Oracle Database

- 21c Express(21.0.0.0.0)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to see for output?

Comment: I removed the `plsqldeveloper` tag, which is for a different product (not SQL Developer). I hope you were really talking about SQL Developer, the IDE offered by Oracle itself, and not something else such as PL/SQL Developer, a similarly named but very different product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage  your output panel in SQL Developer:

**Turns on|off verification**

The VERIFY setting controls whether or not SQL*Plus displays before and after images of each line that contains a substitution variable.

```
SET VER[IFY] {OFF | ON}
```

**Turns on|off feedback completely**

The FEEDBACK setting controls whether SQL*Plus displays the number of records returned.You can set a threshold, below which you don't get any feedback regardless of whether the setting is on.

```
SET FEED[BACK] {OFF | ON | row_threshold}
```

Some Links:

[set feedback off](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/set-feedback-off-6384)

[SET FEEDBACK](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-sqlplus-the/0596007469/re63.html)

[SET VERIFY](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-sqlplus-the/0596007469/re106.html)

Answer (score 2):

Substitution variables, like your `&a`, are exclusively an SQL*Plus concept. The only reason SQL Developer knows what to do with it is that SQL Developer supports most of the SQL*Plus scripting language. So your "no sqlplus" requirement (in your question) is nonsensical. Any solution must be a SQL*Plus solution in one way or another.

What you are asking for is very simple. SQL*Plus supports a feature called `verify`, which does exactly what you don't want it to do: showing you the before and after versions of your code. By default it is `on` - all you need to do is to turn it off before you run your code.

Another thing is the displaying of just your value in the output. By default the `serveroutput` feature is off; to see the output from `dbms_output.put_line()` you must turn it on. It is not clear if you have done that.

So, before you run your code, you must run these **two** SQL*Plus commands; the first one is the one you were asking about, the second one is to see the output from `put_line()`. Note that both are SQL*Plus commands; they are **not** terminated with semicolon (although SQL Developer will not throw an error if they are).

```
set verify off
set serveroutput on
```

As an aside, SQL*Plus tolerates some syntax errors, so your code will run as written (unless it's surrounded by other code); but technically, you are missing a forward slash on a line by itself at the end of your code, to indicate the end of a PL/SQL block.

In the editor window:

```
set verify off
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
  a NUMBER;
BEGIN
  a:=&a;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a);
end;
/
```

Pop-up window asks for value for `a`; I enter the value 5 and hit the OK button

Script output (lower pane):

```
5


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If your next question is "how do I make it so that `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed` does not appear in the output window" - the answer is similar:

```
set feedback off
```

(also a SQL*Plus command, understood by SQL Developer, and **not** terminated with a semicolon).